# what is Centos 5's apache user/group

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

HI I know this is basic but can anyone tell me what the default user/group names are for apache 2 on centos 5/6 please. Google is just giving me junk.

Comment: hey can anyone explain why this was closed as off topic? thanks and sorry if i'd missed something.

Comment: I found this useful.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

apache.

Checking by:

```
# egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
User apache
Group apache
```

Answer (score 4):

It is apache/apache. It is configurable as User and Group in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

`apache` for both releases.(pad)(pad)